# Событийное открытие веб-страницы на Groovy

Tags: groovy

Есть ли в Groovy функции для открытия веб-страниц по событию?

Кейс: при создании объекта необходимо сделать автоматический редирект на другую страницу (без клика на ссылку).

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: уточните все подробности вопроса. "кейс" - это тест-кейс из какой-то среды? или чего еще касается вопрос, помимо groovy?

Comment: речь о каком-то веб-фреймворке?

Comment: Вопрос снят, решился силами фреймворка, которым я пользуюсь. Спасибо.